# Can I route music that's playing on my computer into Facetime?

Tags: music, facetime

I'm using facetime with a headset, while also listening to music.

How do I play the music I'm listening to my friend, over facetime?

Comment: I've tried using JackOSX, but it doesn't list any of Facetime, Songbird or Chrome as input or output devices, when I'm using any of them.

Comment: To be able to live stream (route) your music you will need a direct connection/access to your friends computer, something like Remote Sharing. That is since you use headset, if you were to use your speaker than it is no problem.